# AWS SDK C++ Signature V2

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, digital-signature, aws-sdk

I am just wondering is there any way to specify Signature V2 authorization mechanism in aws-sdk-cpp? I use S3Client

I patched sdk by hardcoding V2 format in aws-sdk-cpp-core/source/auth/AWSAuthSigner.cpp

`ss << "AWS" << " " << credentials.GetAWSAccessKeyId() << ":" << finalSignature;`

But how I can do this right?

Comment: Don't forget to add *often used* tags with many followers, definitely always specify the language. Do  read the tag descriptions, "signature" here has a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Sigv2 is deprecated in favor of Sigv4. The only service that still requires sigv2 is SDB, which you probably shouldn't be writing new code against.

Is this for SDB or another service?